# Is it a proper expression?

Tags: word-usage, informal-language

I want to say sorry in advance since it might sound really ambiguous and hard to get what I want to know. 
Anyway today, I was going to explain to a delivery guy who was trying to get into my apartment that my phone is not connected to or registered for the callbox at the front of my apartment because my phone is California number but the call box only works with NY number.

Can I just say that the call box isn't working cause my phone number is California number? 
Do you think people will get what that is??

Comment: Do you really need to go into so much detail to a **delivery guy**? Why not just say that the call box doesn't work with your phone?

Comment: I know but I also gotta tell this to other people including my friends so I was just wondering how to express this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
The call-box for my apartment is currently out of order.
```

If you feel like you want to add when that might change, then perhaps add something like;

`I expect it to be working next week.`

Why it isn't working is probably not something anyone besides you, and whomever is fixing it, needs to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- That call-box won't connect to my phone.

You could follow that up with:

- I've got a California number.